# Specify startup monitor for UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

In a UWP desktop app , is there a way to force the application to open on a specific monitor. (in my case I have a laptop and extra screen connected to the laptop, so I want the specify the startup screen in code)

I used the following code in winforms:

```
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

if (Screen.AllScreens.Length == 1)
            {
              Application.Run(new frmMain());
            }
else
{
    //select largest monitor and set new monitor
    Rectangle bounds = screens[LargestScreen].Bounds;
    frm.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    Application.Run(frm);
}
```

Any idea how to implement the above in a UWP app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create [multiple views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views) for the app and use [`ProjectionManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ProjectionManager) class with method [`StartProjectingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ProjectionManager#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ProjectionManager_StartProjectingAsync_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to show the secondary view on another screen. You may do this in [`OnLaunched`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application) method then once the app launch the secondary view will show on the screen you want.

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
    } 
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;  
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }
        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
   ///Get all the screens.
    String projectorSelectorQuery = ProjectionManager.GetDeviceSelector();
    var outputDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(projectorSelectorQuery);
    //if(outputDevices.Count==1)
    //{

    //}
    int thisViewId;
    int newViewId = 0;
    ///Choose one screen for display .
    DeviceInformation showDevice = outputDevices[1];
    thisViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        { 
        }          
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
    ///Create a new view
    await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;          
        Window.Current.Activate();
        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(newViewId, thisViewId, showDevice); 

}
```

But it seems like the first view cannot be directly show on other screens since the `StartProjectingAsync` method requires a new view id. The first view that’s created when your app starts is called the main view.  You don’t create this view; it’s created by the app. The main view's thread serves as the manager for the app, and all app activation events are delivered on this thread. And the main view cannot be closed, so the main first view will still leave on the first screen.

Details please reference the [Projection official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection).

Comment: Thanks alot , you answered my question.